# How to create a constant current source from a 12V,19AH Battery which is load independent?

Tags: battery-operated, coil, constant-current

My intention of connecting a copper coil directly to Battery is to basically make the copper coil red hot to boil water. What I have observed is when I connect the 12V,19AH Battery to the 15mm thickness 50 turn copper coil, the Battery tends to drain quickly and the voltage shown by a multi-meter of the battery confirms the draining. On the other hand, when a 30V,10A Laboratory Power Supply is connected to the same coil, it gives a stable current of 9A at 9V, 10A at 10V and trips OFF above 10V. With 10A of current the heating of the coil achieved is fair enough that serves my purpose. How can I provide the coil a consistent of 10A of current which will also stop the draining of the Battery at such a fast rate which otherwise would had been greater than 100A?

Comment: Can you describe more accurately what you are trying to do? will your copper coil sit in the water? and how much resistance does the coil have?

Comment: If the lab supply gives 9A at 9V and 10A at 10V, what makes you think the battery is giving 100A at 12V?

Comment: measure the resistance of the coil (hint: it's 1), then divide by 1/10 to get volts.

Comment: The resistance of the coil could be less than 1 and the lab supply is current limiting based on voltage (weird I know, but stranger things have happened - and it a good assumption that the supply has some current limiting or it wouldn't be a very good one..).

Comment: I don't understand why you don't buy a water boiler designed for the purpose. Perhaps I just misunderstand. But something like this: https://accessories.lazydays.com/roadpro-rpbh-012-12v-beverage-heater-03-1068?cid=52-0013-05&gclid=Cj0KEQjwrYbIBRCgnY-OluOk89EBEiQAZER58pVPxYuHgDMngYVGXCcLjoriwbRV5UBUS0RHWmmL2WQaAguy8P8HAQ

Comment: @Finbarr It was my assumption on the basis of the resistance value I measured across the coil which came about to be 0.1E. But since its a coil the resultant current may be less. But as per my observation, the battery I am taking about drains up in 10-12 minutes. Thats why I assumed this conclusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is putting a resistor in series of the right value: 12V (nom) / 10 A = 1.2 ohm. Depending on the battery capacity (Ah) and the state of charge, the voltage at its terminals while discharging might be more (fully charged, large battery) or slightly less.
Good. But this is your heater itself! So, all the dissipated heat shall go to your water and in this case your system would be efficiently serving its purpose. Just fabricate a wire arrangement that gives you more or less 1 ohm.
For a conductor Ohm's Law says R = resistivity * length / squaresection = rho*L/S

- with copper: hard, because rho when heated to high temperature is still low (something more than 20 mohm/m/mm2; for robustness you may choose a cross section of some mm2, e.g. 4, and you end up with 5 mohm/m, so you need 200 m coil to make 1 ohm. And it's not as hygienic as steel may be
- steel: steel has a 20-40 times larger resistivity; [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) gives at 20°C temperature 1.7 10^-8 for Copper, 6.9 10^-7 for stainless steel, so 40 times. With this material and same cross section of 4 mm2 you need only 5-6 m of length, that fits your need.
- if you have smaller steel wires you can put them in parallel; if you have a total of 2 mm2 cross section, you reduce length to about 3 m.

Of course you might solutions based on DC/DC converters claiming higher efficiency or better regulation. But all the heat you create in the load is going into the water (feeding cables from battery excluded), fine current regulation is not a concern, so the simple scheme calculated above works.
Brown wires are copper feeding cables from battery to heating coil, made of the said steel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZk93P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I had tried with a parallel combination of 5 resistors having value 22E / 10W. But the temperature of the coil simply stopped rising. Also the resistors got heated up pretty much but a resultant temperature enough to boil the water wasn't reached which otherwise happened without the resistors (although only for short time till the battery did not drain)..

Comment: This is what I was saying: you do not need resistors. Use a **steel** wire that gives you the right resistance for the current you need (see last two bullets above in my answer); put a pair of short copper wires to connect battery and coil. That's it.

Comment: To better control the current, you can even include in series 1-2 additional short sections of steel wire (e.g. each 1 m long), so that you have created a variable resistor with 2-3 taps, and you can tap the shorter steel wire when you need a slightly lower resistor to counteract the reduced output current of the depleting battery.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I provide the coil a consistent of 10A of current which will also stop the draining of the Battery

A regulated power supply is wasted if you just want a  heater.  Consider
using a transformer (such as a soldering gun) that has a high-current low
voltage secondary, and run the wire on AC current.   A hundred-watt
soldering gun, of course, is the smallest that can match the heat
output of 10V at 10A.  Expect higher current, but lower voltage,
and adjust the wire dimensions accordingly.

Copper, at red heat, oxidizes and won't last long.  High
temperature wire, like nichrome, might be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is not surprising that the current is very high if you have a copper coil, as you're then just making a short circuit. If the coil is dunked in water as is, there will also be some conduction in the water (the conductivity of water varies a lot depending on the type of water; tap water, distilled water, salt water etc), which will be fun. For sanity's sake, I shall assume you have insulated the copper coil with something similar to heat shrink.

The properties that limit your current then are: internal resistance of the battery and resistance of the copper, two resistances in series. Current through these depend on their value and the voltage across them, as per Ohm's Law (V=IR). This means that you'll need a constant current circuit to drive it. Have you tried any kind of internet search for "constant current circuit"? There are quite a few options out there depending on what you want to do.

As for how to get your battery to last longer: you will drain it at a constant current. The only way to make it last longer is either to draw less current or to have a bigger battery.

Comment: not all discharge profiles provide the same amount of power...

Comment: No, but if you're going to have a fixed, constant, current there isn't much you can do to change the discharge profile.

Comment: Would like to clarify a few things first, I haven't dunk the coil yet in the water. The resistor part you have mentioned is also what I have tried. I tried connecting 5 resistors each having 22E / 10W all in parallel to each other having coil in series connection. These resistors got heated up more than the coil itself did. Maybe the dissipation rate here is more than the accumulation rate of heat happening here which is stopping the arrangement to achieve higher temperatures?